# player.setFoodLevel doesn't work

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a KitPvP plugin for Bukkit. I have run across an error, and I was wondering if someone could help me.

So, I have a `Main.java` as my Main Class. I registered the events in `Hunger.java` but the code won't execute in Minecraft. All the other aspects of the plugin work so far besides this. Here is the code for `Hunger.java`:

```
package com.lobbyist.junk.kitpvp;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;

public class Hunger implements Listener{

    public void onPlayerInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event){
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        player.setFoodLevel(20);
    }

}
```

How do I make player.setFoodLevel work?

EDIT: I just forgot to add an EventHandler annotation. *Stupid me*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from [the documentation](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference), you have not registered this event handler as an `EventHandler`.

Something like:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    player.setFoodLevel(20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the `@EventHandler` annotation, and you also have to register events in your `onEnable()` method:

*In your main class (the one that extends JavaPlugin):*

```
public class MyMainClass extends JavaPlugin{

  public void onEnable(){
    //format:
    //this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new MyClassThatImplementsListener());
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new Hunger());

    //onEnable() stuff that you currently have
  }

  //other stuff
}
```

*in your Hunger class (your listener, that you posted in the question):*

```
public class Hunger implements Listener{

  @EventHandler //you need this annotation above ALL events
  public void onPlayerInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    player.setFoodLevel(20);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot I needed to add @EventHandler it completely slipped my mind, thanks so much. Also I do have it registered. I have getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Hunger(), getInstance()); replacing the class name, I use it for all my extra classes.